# Can't update Ubuntu 12.04 - failed to fetch repository info

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, software-sources

I have a freshly installed 12.04. Running the update manager gives me this:

[image]

I even changed my update server ( by selecting "Select Best Server" ). Checking around the net gave me no solutions. I have also seen similar questions around but none helped.

Updating from terminal gives me [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5663913/)

[My sources.list file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5663906/)

Comment: Did you try the Main Server rather than the one recommended by "Select Best Server"?

Comment: @fossfreedom yes i have... same error

Comment: Do you have internet access?  Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes (obviously) and no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how but some how it started to work. :)
I can't tell what made it work but here is my current system status when it started to work.

The Server was set to `Main Server`
There were no 3rd party repositories.

The MAIN part is some how make the system **auto check for updates**
That solved my problem and should maybe solve your problem too.